# Can grub recognize a "degraded" raid1 mdadm partition?

Tags: grub, raid, btrfs, mdadm, software-raid

Grub can boot(I have tried) from a zfs "degraded" raid1, is simple: create two zfs pools, one is boot, one is root, each one is raid1...and grub load Linux, with two disk, or with only one active, one or two.
I want to try a similar thing with btrfs root raid1 + mdadm raid1 on ext4 for boot.
As I known the latest grub on Slackware current can recognize md raid on boot(metadata 0.90). I configure my system on this way

```
fdisk -l /dev/vda
Disk /dev/vda: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7715105B-51CD-9A45-9D05-E2C8161E51E9

Device        Start       End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/vda1      2048   1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/vda2   1050624   9439231  8388608    4G Linux swap
/dev/vda3   9439232  11536383  2097152    1G Linux RAID
/dev/vda4  11536384 104857566 93321183 44.5G Linux filesystem


fdisk -l /dev/vdb
Disk /dev/vdb: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7715105B-51CD-9A45-9D05-E2C8161E51E9

Device        Start       End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/vdb1      2048   1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/vdb2   1050624   9439231  8388608    4G Linux swap
/dev/vdb3   9439232  11536383  2097152    1G Linux RAID
/dev/vdb4  11536384 104857566 93321183 44.5G Linux filesystem
```

this is the fstab

```
LABEL=SWAP       swap             swap        defaults            0   0
LABEL=ROOT       /                btrfs       defaults,degraded   1   1
LABEL=BOOT       /boot            ext4        defaults            1   2
/dev/vda1        /boot/efi        vfat        defaults            1   2
devpts           /dev/pts         devpts      gid=5,mode=620      0   0
proc             /proc            proc        defaults            0   0
tmpfs            /dev/shm         tmpfs       nosuid,nodev,noexec 0   0
```

this is the /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=$( sed 's/Slackware /Slackware-/' /etc/slackware-version )
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200 rootflags=degraded"
GRUB_TERMINAL="console serial"
```

finally the mkinitrd.conf

```
SOURCE_TREE="/boot/initrd-tree"
CLEAR_TREE="1"
OUTPUT_IMAGE="/boot/initrd.gz"
KERNEL_VERSION="$(ls /var/log/packages/kernel-generic-*-x86_64-* |cut -d - -f 3)"
KEYMAP="it"
MODULE_LIST="btrfs:ext4:vfat:xhci-hcd:hid:usbhid:ochi-hcd:uhci-hcd:uhci-hcd:ehci-hcd:virtio-net:virtio-ring:virtio-blk:virtio-pci"
LUKSDEV="/dev/disk/by-uuid/b97cbe7d-c5e5-432e-adc4-659ed80dd65f:/dev/disk/by-uuid/ec4fd069-0bd2-4b53-90e2-e493c50070f1"
ROOTDEV="/dev/vda4"
ROOTFS="btrfs"
RESUMEDEV="/dev/disk/by-label/SWAP"
RAID="1"
LVM="0"
UDEV="1"
```

I update initrd and grub

```
mkinitrd -B -F
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

i reboot and work: It ask me two password for two encrypted luks devices and go directly on login.
I tried to boot from the second disk and...

[image]

As you can see the second efi partition is recognize, but not the md raid1 degraded partition, if I attach the first disk works fine.
Of course I had installed grub on boot disks

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --recheck --efi-dir=/boot/efi /dev/vda
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --recheck --efi-dir=/boot/efi /dev/vdb
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: was not a problem of grub but of EFI!
Booting with the classic method(no efi + biosboot partition) grub can recognize mdadm and boot fine from the second disk.